# Async Clipboard API - clipboardchange event not fired

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, clipboard

Has anyone been able to hook the clipboardchange event of the new Async Clipboard API? I am trying this:

```
navigator.clipboard.addEventListener('clipboardchange', function (e) {
                console.log("navigator clipboardchange");
            });
```

But it never fires.

Comment: because `addEventListener` doesn't exist. If you type `navigator.clipboard` into the console and look at the `__proto__` you won't see it.

Comment: document.addEventListener for clipboardchange is also not working. but document.addEventListener for copy, cut, paste event is working. Could be a bug?

Comment: my guess is it is not implemented yet in any browser, although the other parts of the async clipboard specs work. 
https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#clipboard-event-clipboardchange

Answer (score 3):

At least for chrome this isn't implemented, see [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933608) for more details.

Reading the comments, there does seem to be some pressure to implement it, otherwise you'll have to poll

Answer (score 1):

I know it doesn't really answer the question but this is a hack that will do the same :

```js
async startClipboardPoll () {
  try {
    let clipboardContent;

    // Comment the following line
    // if you want to run <CODE> when clipboard change from other pages
    // (when the user focus back on your app)
    window.onfocus = async function () { clipboardContent = await navigator.clipboard.readText() }

    while (true) {
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500)) // wait
      const previousContent = clipboardContent
      try {
        clipboardContent = await navigator.clipboard.readText()
      } catch (e) {
        // This function may fail if you focus another webpage
        // just ignoring and continuing.
        continue
      }
      if (previousContent == undefined) {
        continue
      }
      if (clipboardContent !== previousContent) {
        /*******************
         * Clipboard changed !
         * <CODE> here
         * `clipboardContent` is the clipboard content
         ******************/
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn('something went wrong');
    // maybe warn the user here this functionality is not available
  }
}
```

Then call this function somewhere in your code.